# getting the standard error of linear regression coefficient using bootstrap

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to calculate the standard error of linear regression coefficient using bootstrap technique (100 resamples) but the result I got is zero, which is not normal. I think something is wrong with the bootstrap part of the code. Do you know how to fix my code?

```
x, y = np.genfromtxt("input.txt", unpack=True) 

#regression part
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print std_err

#bootstrap part of the code
A = np.random.choice(x, size=100, replace=True)
B = np.random.choice(y, size=100, replace=True)
slope2, intercept2, r_value2, p_value2, std_err2 = stats.linregress(A,B)
print std_err2
```

**input.txt:**

```
-1.08   -1.07
-2.62   -2.56
-2.84   -2.79
-2.22   -2.16
-3.47   -3.55
-2.81   -2.79
-2.86   -2.71
-3.41   -3.42
-4.18   -4.21
-3.50   -3.48
-5.67   -5.55
-6.83   -6.95
-6.13   -6.13
-8.34   -8.19
-7.82   -7.83
-9.86   -9.58
-8.67   -8.62
-9.81   -9.81
-8.39   -8.30
```

Comment: what library are you getting `stats` from? Please include your library imports so other people can easily run your code.

Comment: I am removing the matplotlib tag. This has nothing to do with it

Comment: When I run your code (assuming `stats` is from `scipy`) I get 0.007415 for std_err and 0.099598 for std_err2? Neither is zero.

Comment: I am getting `0.00741473410217` and `0.105542871364`. Scipy version `'0.19.1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issues with your above code running in Python 3.6.1.  Maybe check that your scipy version is current?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x, y = np.genfromtxt("./input.txt", unpack=True)
slope_1, intercept_1, r_val_1, p_val_1, stderr_1 = stats.linregress(x, y)
print(slope_1) # 0.9913080927081567
print(stderr_1) # 0.007414734102169809

A = np.random.choice(x, size=100, replace=True)
B = np.random.choice(y, size=100, replace=True)

slope_2, incercept_2, r_val_2, p_val_2, stderr_2 = stats.linregress(A, B)
print(slope_2) # 0.11429903085322253
print(stderr_2) # 0.10158283281966374
```

---

**Correctly Bootstrapping the Data**

The correct way to do this would be to use the `resample` method from `sklearn.utils`.  This method handles the data in a consistent array format.  Since your data is an x, y pair, the y value is dependent on your x value.  If you randomly sample x and y independently you lose that dependency and your resampled data will not accurately represent your population.

```
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.utils import resample
import numpy as np

x, y = np.genfromtxt("./input.txt", unpack=True)
slope_1, intercept_1, r_val_1, p_val_1, stderr_1 = stats.linregress(x, y)
print(slope_1) # 0.9913080927081567
print(stderr_1) # 0.007414734102169809

A, B = resample(x, y, n_samples=100) # defaults to w/ replacement

slope_2, incercept_2, r_val_2, p_val_2, stderr_2 = stats.linregress(A, B)
print(slope_2) # 0.9864339054638176
print(stderr_2) # 0.002669659193615103
```

Comment: Well, there are 19 (x,y) pairs for x and y arrays in the input file. The routine code generates 100 x and 100 values seperately not 100 x and 100 y arrays. I think it is wrong. The code should generate 100 x and 100 y arrays for 2d array. As you see that slope_1 and slope_2 are very different. That is not normal.

Comment: @erhan I have updated the answer to correctly answer your issue.